# Different z-index values

Tags: html, css

I didn't know how to properly address the problem I have so title is not telling pretty much anything, but anyways the problem I have is in this piece of code:

https://jsfiddle.net/bnh3487n/

```
div {
width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

#one {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

#sub {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}

#two {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

So is it possible so that the green div is in front of the blue one and so that it stays child element of the red div. I know that this z-index: 3 isn't working but don't have any ideas how to soulution would work;

Comment: Can you change your HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because `z-index` only works if the 2 elements are siblings, not parents and children.

Basically `#two` is queued before the whole `#one` container:

```
 0   #two

-1   #one
```

and `#one` contains a `#sub` that is not outside of `#one` and `#one` is still behind `#two`, so `#sub` is too, behind `#two`.

Think of `z-index` like this:

```
              -1                              0

     /--------------------/         /--------------------/
    /                    /|        /                    /|
   /      #one          / |       /      #two          / |
  /                    /  |      /                    /  |
 /-2  -1  0  1  2  3--/   |     /-2  -1  0  1  2  3--/   |      Observer (o ͜L o )
 |                    |   |     |                    |   |
 |               #sub |   |     |                    |   |
 |                    |   /     |                    |   /
 |                    |  /      |                    |  /
 |                    | /       |                    | /
 |--------------------|/        |--------------------|/
```

Comment: Thanks for the visual representation, it's just the right picture why i thought this wouldn't work. I'll change my html structure then so that it suits my needs

Comment: @JesusChrist great, you're welcome, good luck to your project :)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer with your HTML/CSS is **no**.

`z-index` has a couple of rules:

- You have to set a `position` with `z-index`
- A child cannot display above a parent if the parent z-index is set, also. E.g. A parent has a `z-index` of 2 and a child div has a `z-index` of 3, the child will still not display above the parent (unless using minus values).

You need to change your HTML structure so the divs are siblings.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) provides explanation as to how the z-index works.  In a nutshell, the z-index applies to all child objects.

Only solution is for you to remove the "sub" div and place it outside of "one"