# Notification Popup displaying in background

Tags: javascript, css, html, notifications, popup

I have a **notification popup** just like the one on SO and it looks fine in Firefox [image: popup in firefox]  
**BUT** in **chrome** it goes in background as shown in below image [image: in chrome]
I have tried increasing z-index but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS code. That would make it much easier for people to help you solve your issue.

Comment: `z-index` issues are usually caused by incorrect `position` values. `z-index` will only work, if the element's `position` is set to `absolute` or `relative`.

Comment: `z-index` elements need to be siblings. So if you set a `z-index` inside another element and one outside. They may not work as you expect. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272916/different-z-index-values/32273125#32273125

Comment: Also, adding to my previous comment, I wouldn't say it's a duplicate question, but the misunderstanding of `z-index` as well as the solution of the problem are the same. I'd say the two are similar questions.